# Can Verifiable Random Functions be used to pick a random node from a pool?

Tags: random-number-generator, randomness, pseudo-random-function, verifiability, verifiable-random-function

Let's say that I have a decentralized system and I have a list of nodes published on a public log like a blockchain. I want a node `A` to be able to connect to another node `B`. `B` should be chosen randomly from a subset `S` of the list of all nodes. Once `B` is chosen I want the other nodes in the system to verify whether `B` was actually chosen randomly. We can assume that every node is able to compute `S` so my question is: Can `A` use a verifiable random function to choose a node from `S` which we call `B` and have all the other nodes be able to verify that the node `B` I chose was the node that was supposed to be chosen?

Comment: Sure sounds like you can do this, if every node reliably knows every other node's public VRF verification key.

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage Thank you. My idea was to use it as follows: Every element in `S` is assigned an index with some specific criteria so every node assigns the same indexes to the elements of `S`. Then the VRF is used to generate a random value `a` and the proof `p`. The element in `S`  chosen is the one with index `i = a % n` where `n` is the max index. Other nodes then can use the proof to verify the correctness of the election. Is this the proper way of using VRF?

Comment: I am highly interested in this problem as well, @David please let me know if you've made any progress on this =) Thanks!

Comment: You may be interested to read about [Algorand](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/454), which uses VRFs to pick which users get to propose a block in a particular round.